# Reality check for my understanding of map space of infinity category

Tags: category-theory

So the map space is $\operatorname{Map}_C(a,b)$, and it is the pullback of $\operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^1,C)\to C\times C$ along $\Delta^0\to C\times C$.

In my understanding $\pi_0(\operatorname{Map}_C(a,b))$ is the homotopy classes of maps so $\operatorname{Map}_C(a,b)$ should carry higher order data, right?

Then $\operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^1,C)$ should also carry higher order data, right?

The way $\operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^1,C)$ carries higher order data should be that for a degenerate simplex [image: 1] the functor maps it to [image: 2], right?

Please help me to do these reality checks, big thanks.

Comment: Typically what is meant by "higher-order data" here is that $\operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^1, C)$ is not just a set of functors, but an $\infty$-category itself whose objects are functors, 1-morphisms are natural transformations, etc.

Comment: @JHF thanks. i think i used the wrong informal description here. but i think you get what i mean so do you think i'm understanding this correctly?

Comment: I don't think you've touched upon "higher-order data" in your example.  Of course, how this is expressed would depend on your model of $\infty$-categories.

Comment: It's very unclear what your last sentence is trying to say. The higher-order data in $Fun(\Delta^1,C)$ comes from its $n$-simplices for $n>0$, which are maps $\Delta^1\times \Delta^n\to C$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I think I get it now and here's a note for anyone who has the same inquiry: the $\operatorname{Fun}$ does not mean $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathrm{wKan}}$, but rather $\operatorname{Hom}_{\infty\text{-Cat}}$.

The latter does not have face and degeneracy maps, so the simplicial identities does not need to be satisfied.